# Wordpress plugin - Publish post is slow

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I created a wordpress plugin in which on post publish I will call a function which will send a post request to my server with blog post ID,post head and URL.

Everything is working fine,but the 'publish_post' is very slow,as it waits for server response.I'm using PHP curl method for server connection.

I even tried

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0.1);
```

But doesn't make any change in response delay.

```
function on_post_publish( $ID) {

    $subject=get_the_title( $ID );

    $url= get_permalink( $ID )

    send_data_to_server($subject,$url,$ID);
}
add_filter(  'publish_post',  'on_post_publish', 10, 2 );    

function send_data_to_server($subject,$client_url,$ID){


    $url = "http://....../plugin.php"; 

    $data="subject=".$subject."&url=".$client_url."&post_id=".$ID;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0.1);

        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

}
```

Comment: How long do you wait for a response? Also is there any extra code for the processing of the information what `$json_response` seems to be waiting for basicly. From experience if you query the wp_posts table that means it will have to sort through all the post/pages/attachments. Which can be very slow.

Comment: @Musk I'm using the data to send emails to my subscribed users from the server.It's taking about 25-30s to get the response

Comment: also this line will flush the connection everytime so it might slow it down a little but shoudn't be that much. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);`

Comment: @Musk Ok,I'm not using the response from server.But is there any way to complete the Wordpress post function immediately

Comment: i did something once that might be appropriate for you, i basicly posted the information with a status `meta_key` called `_post_email_status` and had a Wordpress CRON cycle every 5 minute sending the information and changing its status. This would allow you to basicly post the information right away and leave the secondary process complete on its own. Thus you would not be left to wait for all operations to be completed all at once.